# Let $x,y,z\in L^2(0,T)$ with $x,z>0$. Then are there infinitely many $f_i\in L^2(0,T)$ so that

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, integration

> Let $x,y,z\in L^2(0,T)$ with $x,z>0$. Then are there infinitely many $f_i\in L^2(0,T)$ with $\|f_i\|_2$ uniformly bounded so that
> $$\int_0^T [x(s)f_i(s)f_j(s)-y(s)(f_i(s)+f_j(s))+z(s)]ds=0,$$
> forall $i\neq j$?

This seems plausible, but it is not clear to me how to show it. I note that this is a inner product + two linear functionals + a constant. I tried some tricks from that. For example choose an ONB of the inner product and then choose the ones of those that satisfy $$\int_0^T y(s) f_i(s)ds=\frac12\int_0^T z(s)ds.$$

Comment: @user93480 Got your point, sorry. I'll delete the previous comments. I still feel like I'm on the right track, but I'll write an answer next if anything.

Comment: Well, $z$ is not really relevant to the question.  You might as well instead just ask for $\int_0^T [x(s)f_i(s)f_j(s)-y(s)(f_i(s)+f_j(s))]ds=C$ where $C\leq 0$ is a constant.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, that is correct. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the most basic example, say $x=z=1$, $y=0$? What can you say about $||f_1+\ldots +f_n||^2$ for big $n$ in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Just following up on @Aleksei Kulikov ‘s comment, the answer seems to be that it depends on $x,y,z$. Suppose the relation holds with $x=z=1$, $y=0$, $T=1$, and $\| f_i\| |\le M$. Then the given relation becomes $\langle f_i , f_j \rangle = -1$, and so

$$
\| f_1 + \cdots + f_n \|^2 = \sum^n \| f_i\|^2  + \sum_{i\ne j} \langle f_i, f_j \rangle \le nM^2- n(n-1).
$$
The right hand side is negative for $n$ sufficiently large, which is an evident contradiction.